# Tableau Week() Function Start on Monday instead of Sunday

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau 10.5, I want to have my Week(date) start on a Monday, but it automatically starts on Sunday. How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of the worksheets, right-click the Data Source, then select “Date Properties”. From here, you can modify Week Start Day, Fiscal Year Start and Date Format.

Comment: is this going to modify the Week calculation for all the worksheets connected to that data source?